# Searching for each line of a text file in another text file using Unix shell script

Tags: file, unix, comparison

I want to search for each line of a text file in another text file using Unix shell script. Consider these two text files:

file1:

```
HELEN  
JOE  
FRED  
HARRY  
TERRY
```

file2:

```
hello FRED  
bert  
JOE  
hi there  
HARRY  
JOHN  
PETE was here  
hello STEVE
```

The required output should look like this:

```
HELEN not found in file2  
JOE found in file2  
FRED found in file2  
HARRY found in file2  
TERRY not found in file2
```

The script I have used is as follows:

```
while read name  
do  
   found="no"  
   while read line  
   do  
      echo $line | grep $name >/dev/null  
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]  
      then  
         echo $name found in file2  
         found="yes"  
         break  
      fi  
   done < file2  
   if [ $found = "no" ]  
   then  
      echo $name not found in file2  
   fi
done < file1
```

This is the output I'm getting, which is not correct

```
not found in file2   
found in file2  
found in file2  
found in file2                                                                               
not found in file2
```

Is there something wrong with the script or the logic used here?

Comment: Your code works as expected for me... i.e. it shows what you have under required output. I am using bash-3.2.57 on OS X

Comment: @hharishh Which shell do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
while read f; do
  if grep -q -o $f file2
  then
    echo $f found in file2
  else
    echo $f not fount in file2
  fi
done<file1
```